# Editing php.ini won't solve the problem of memory limit 2mb (wordpress) on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: wordpress, apache, php-ini

FINAL TEST:

Just for test purposes, I removed the php.ini file via SSH, then I created and updated that very file again (my own version with a different value for upload_max_filesize with a value of 100M). Nothing has changed and the phpinfo.php file still shows 2M as a default value for upload_max_filesize.
Something must be wrong.

THE PROBLEM:

I've just set up a LAMP server on my Amazon Linux 2 cloud service. My goal is to install a WordPress website with everything someone needs.

At this point, I'm almost satisfied except for a problem.

For some reason, I'm not able to upload a file bigger than 2mb.

I read this tutorial and I followed: https://aws.amazon.com/it/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/wordpress-themes-2mb/.

I was able to change the php.ini file through the SSH vim editor, but it didn't work and on my WordPress admin panel, in the upload section (I'm using a plugin to export a theme) it is shown:

```
 Maximum upload file size: 2 MB.
```

Now, I've already changed my php.ini file:

```
memory_limit = 128M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```

but nothing has changed.

I've also changed the code in my wp-config file like that:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

But really, nothing changed too.

I added this snippet in Apache:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 128M
php_value post_max_size 128M
php_value memory_limit 256M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

And I created another file in this folder /etc/php.d called 30-custom.ini with the exacted file that I modified earlier (php.ini).

Still nothing..

Is there something wrong with my approach?

UPDATE:

Furthermore in my phpinfo.php file, I got this details:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files /etc/php.d
upload_max_filesize 2M  2M
```

but, in my folder /ect my file php.ini shows this:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

So, even if I modified the file, the changes don't affect the server.

Comment: have you restart apache?

Comment: yes, with this command:

sudo service httpd reload

Comment: check your php.ini exact location. How to get this location ? create one php file and add <?php echo phpinfo();?> check exact path which was refer for php.ini. Chances is high having multiple php.ini

Comment: I did it, it is the same exact file that I'm modifying and there are two different values. I will publish the problem in my update

Comment: I tried something: I removed the php.ini file, I created my own and I uploaded again that very file. Nothing has changed, the value is still the same

Comment: Run this command `find / -type f -name php.ini -print`. How many `php.ini` files do you have?

Comment: 2) Do you have `upload_max_filesize` or `post_max_size` set in Wordpress `functions.php`? 3) Are the same values set in `.htaccess`?

Comment: No, I did in wp-config.php and .htaccess. The problem was that I had to restart the apache server in a different way I guess